# Access 2016 system resource exceeded / not enough memory

Tags: ms-access

When trying to export to PDF or print to PDF in Access 2016 I am getting a system resource exceeded message or "There is enough memory" error message........any advice on what is likely to be wrong?

Comment: Hopefully this isn't your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575487/ms-access-there-isnt-enough-memory-to-perform-this-operation

Comment: Does report use subforms? Does query source use subqueries? Any custom VBA code? Please post all details of report as a calculation somewhere might be the problem.